# Live Reload on IceWeasel?

Tags: raspberry-pi, node.js, iceweasel

I'm trying to get an LiveReload nodejs server on Raspberry Pi 3 working with Iceweasel, newest version. The Live-Reload Plugin is installed and activated, however the website doesn't reload.
The server is running and is waiting for the browser to connect, see the screen.
[commandLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5gK7.jpg)

Does anybody know if the handshake was sucessfull when the client sends a message? The last line in the command line stays the last line all the time.
The file to survey is "default.htm"

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Comment: Suggestion: I realize it was faster perhaps to photograph the screen on your Pi and then attach the image, however this deprives search engines from finding the contents of your log/error messages - if there is any way to copy/paste them into your question, that might help you get a faster response.